# BJT Transistor (NPN and PNP ) Power Supply Monitoring Circuit

Tags: power-supply, transistors, analog, bjt

I am Understanding the Behavior of the following circuit with the help of simulation.

Following Circuit Gives High signal at the opto coupler output when the supply voltage goes (V3) below 13.68 V.

Now if i remove the R1 , R2 , R3 and Q2 i Still gate the same result .

then whats purpose using  Q2 here if the circuit behaves same with its absence   ?

Kindly help me understand the functionality  of Q2 .

I believe this is not current limiter circuit for power supply ( V3 ).[image]

Fig 1 Actual Circuit 
[image]

Fig 2 Without R1, R2, R3 and Q2

Thank you in advance

Comment: Poor man's hysteresis loop with a weak design.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  Could you please  briefly explain how the hysteresis action takes place here ?

Comment: It's a positive feedback loop with low gain, so the threshold is early in each direction lo/hi/lo

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 okay so  its  an  implementation  schmitt trigger using BJT ?

Comment: yes.............................

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  And my Last Doubt is why Q2 is used then even if circuit works fine without it ?

Comment: how noisy it is at output with input on rising or falling edge of 24Vdc ripple at threshold?  I see a gain est. ~15x from 14V to output may or may nor be an issue.  If it is fine for you, why ask?

Comment: @Rohan How much of the circuit do you understand without the parts you removed? Can you put it into words for us? You are asking why the added parts are there and pointing to your observation that they don't seem to "do anything." I get that. I can see why they might not. But I'm not sure how to explain that section, if I'm not sure you follow the rest. (If you follow the rest, though, a fairly simple explanation is possible, I think.)

Comment: @jonk , as per my understanding  , when  V3 ( supply voltage )  starts rising , TR Q1 starts conducting when  the  12v zener comes in operation. TR Q1 starts conducting and goes into saturation after   Which it provides base cureent  to Q2 and  drive  Q2  into saturation.  Now i dont understand how hysterisys is achieved  here using Two transistors. Any words of explanation  is appreciated.

Comment: @Rohan That's probably good enough. You should now be able to derive the following relationship:$$\begin{align*}I_\text{D}&=\frac{V_\text{B}\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_3}\right)-V_\text{D}}{R_4+R_5}\\&\therefore\\V_\text{B}&=\left(V_\text{D}+2\,I_\text{D}\,R_4\right)\frac{R_3}{R_2+R_3}\end{align*}$$ where \$V_\text{B}\$ is the base voltage at \$Q_2\$ and \$I_\text{D}\$ is the current in the photodiode and \$V_\text{D}\$ is the photodiode voltage. Does that help you think about the \$Q_2\$ circuit at question?

Comment: @jonk , you are suggesting  VB is the UTP of  this hysterisis.  If it is , then When  Supply voltage crosse VB value ,  is there any change  in conduction  state of Q2 happens. I have read the Schmitt  trigger using Transistor,  in that case either  of one transistor  is switched  off.  Is it happening  in this case also ?

Comment: The exact thresholds depend on the CTR of the Opto assuming U1-C threshold is Vdd/2 and using @jonk 's formulae with  the bistable conditions will lead you to deriving UTP and LTP.  But it's probably not worth the effort but could be simulated in Falstad in 5 minutes.  The reason I say that is the threshold is so far from 24V that 0.5V~1V **hys-ter-e'-sis** is almost irrelevant.  Unless this is an unregulated supply with large ripple when overloaded at low voltage... then you may get an oscillating fault condition or intermittent UV detect.

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75   This  is actually  under voltage  detection circuit for externally  connected 24 volts  supply. Which  should  alert the microcontroller  when supply goes below 14V and again alert the controller when supply is rising and reaches  12 volts (~2 volts of hysterisis ) .                                                                                         Since my Hysterisis  is very small, even if i remove the  Q2,  not much change is seen ?  Is this understanding  correct  ? Please let me know your comment on this .

Comment: Read my comments again and correct spelling in bold.  Generally Hysteresis is used to eliminated multiple or false triggering due to noise, ripple near the threshold.  If your supply varies significantly with load this much that 15V  is OK even with 2Vpp of ripple, then that’s up to your system design spec and then hysteresis may not be needed.  But if it was say -25% then you might want 10% of hysteresis or Pwr OK = 18V+/- 2.4 or 15.6, 20.4V.  So it all depends on your system spec.

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 @ jonk . I understood  this  now.  Since the hysteresis  is  small ,  even the Q2 is absent , it wont affect the circuit  application in my case.